# How to stop mat-menu closing after clicking the mat-toggle button?

Tags: angular

After I clicked one of the toggle button, the mat-menu closes automatically. I need to stop that
from happening. So that when the user clicks somewhere else the menu closes.

```
     <button [matMEnuTriggerFor]="popoverMenu">Menu</button>
     <mat-menu #popoverMenu="metMenu">
         <mat-button-toggle-group class="xyz" name="portfolioType" 
         (change)="portfolioTypeChange.emit($event.value)" [value]="portfolioType">
              <mat-button-toggle value="gross" disableRipple>Gross</mat-button-toggle>
              <mat-button-toggle value="net" disableRipple>Net</mat-button-toggle>
         </mat-button-toggle-group>
     </mat-menu>
```

Answer (score -1):

in .html

```
<mat-button-toggle-group class="xyz" name="portfolioType" 
     (change)="handleChange($even)" (click) ="stopPropagation($event)"[value]="portfolioType">
in component.ts
stopPropagation(event) {
 event.stopPropagation()
 event.preventDefault()
}
handleChange(event)  {
   // your.emit() code
 
   event.stopPropagation()
   event.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: That did not work. I tried to add another event handler next to change like (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" in the toggle button group. That did not work either.

Comment: use same event.stopPropagation() in your change function  also.
I just saw , you are using (change). i have updated the code

Comment: It has not effect, because the portfolioTypeChange.emit() closes the box when it gets executed